# How to get specific <div class...> with jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

In the source of the site I've got:

```
<div class="blablabla>
```

how to select this part with jsoup?

I don't understand the syntax presented in the doc: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
When I've wrote:

```
Elements e = document.select("div[class=\"blablabla\"]");
```

I got nothing. :(

and when I type:

```
Elements e = document.select("div");
```

then I got all divs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need a better selector and this shall work for you:

```
// selector based on div with class name blablabla

Elements e = document.select("div. blablabla").first(); 

// first used here to return the first of such class type
```

---

Btw, the solution in the link you shared has a similar example to state:

```
Element masthead = doc.select("div.masthead").first();
// div with class=masthead
```

The [`Selector API documentation`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) include all such examples of the matchers and selectors used to find elements.

Comment: How can I get the glosary how to use this strange syntax, bro?

Comment: @WW updated the answer with the link to the Selector API used to find elements.

Comment: @WW Cool. If that helps, do tick mark this as an answer for future relevances.